# Optioning chaining not working for array.length === x

Tags: javascript

```js
let products;

if (products?.length !== 0) {
  console.log('true')
}
```

vs

```js
let products;

if (products && products.length !== 0) {
  console.log('true')
}
```

If there is no product array, example 1 will still run the if statement. Shouldn't the optional chaining check to see if product exists, then check for the length and finally check length to 0?

Example. 2 will not run if product does not exist.

Comment: no, it doesn't check for existence and it is only useful one level deep when the root itself is undefined. from the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) *'Optional chaining cannot be used on a non-declared root object, but can be used with an undefined root object.'*

Comment: Try `if(!!products?.length)`... because if `product` is undefined, your actual condition end up in `if(undefined !==0)`... Which is true. ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Optional chaining does not take precedence over comparison. This

```
if (products?.length !== 0) {
```

is

```
if ((products?.length) !== 0) {
```

It evaluates the chain, then compares the result to 0. If there was a value at the end of the chain, that'll be compared. If the chain failed due to something being nullish, it'll evaluate to `undefined`, and *that* will be compared with 0.

```
if ((undefined) !== 0) {
```

which will always be true.

Since you want the block to run if `products` exists and isn't empty, use

```
if (products?.length) {
```